# Compile go (golang) files seperately and use together

Tags: api, go

i am new in golang, and learnt python;

My question is,
I want to write a program which includes a go program  in runtime if any condition is satisfied in the main program, otherwise it will not include it and run independentaly; if the condition become true, it will include that and run that program. I am come from python and can give you hint in python:-

#SOME CODES

if userQuery=="ip":

```
from . import ipInfo

ip = input("Enter ip: ")

print(ipInfo(ip))
```

elif userQuery==anything:

```
doanything()
```

#SOME CODES

My program is large so I want that it will include in runtime in go.

I am trying to import and run go program at runtime.

Comment: its not possible.

Comment: You might want to look at Go plugins: https://pkg.go.dev/plugin

Comment: There is no „I want“ in „Go“.

Answer (score 1):

Go is a compiled language, so you cannot do things like dynamic import as you can do in scripting language. As mentioned in the comments you can do similar with [plugin](https://pkg.go.dev/plugin), but in that case even you need a compiled version of your code, so you can import it based on your conditions. Plugin concepts, as it name suggests, helping you to add features into your program by releasing new add-ons. Also, note that plugins are not available on Windows.